# Hi, can anyone tell how to check with phone and headset capture for snoop log where codec=SBC

Tags: bluetooth

can anyone tell how to check with phone and headset capture for snoop log where codec=SBC, I have tried with making sbc in phone but it will become as AAC again. Not able to take snoop log as I want only codec = SBC but not able to take. please tell if anyone knows

I have tried by making it SBC from my developer option in phone but after connecting with airpods it will become codec = AAC